# Streaming, recording and transcoding in C#

Tags: c#, video, streaming, transcode

I'm interested in developing an application that is able to grab network streams, transcode (preferably JPEG2000 & H.264) and/or record them and streaming from file.

I've already looked at .net wrappers for ffmpeg (which are mostly incomplete and/or dead), Windows Media Foundation and the VLC plugin, but didn't find a suitable solution there.

Do you know any comfortable, easy to use, preferably managed (or COM) solutions to achieve this?

Comment: Is this so that you can capture streaming movies and save them as distributable files?

Comment: There are no Media APIs which are in the same time powerful, easy to use, complete, interfaced into environment you need, available in various systems etc. You have to cut out what you don't need and hope for something to appear with the remained short list of requirements. With C# you will have Media Foundation if you don't need Vista and older, DirectShow via DirectShow.NET open source wrapper, or custom solution specific for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

1. Use FFmpeg, do all the heavy lifting in native code and wrap it in a c# GUI
2. Use DirectShow/MF. There are passable C# direct show wrappers but you are probably still better of doing the heavy lifting in native code.
3. Look into the Expression Encoder SDK (which can do just about anything the GUI client can do) which may meet your needs depending on redistribution requirements.
4. Use [streamcoders](http://www.streamcoders.com/) (uses IPP as far as I can tell) or something similar that does 1 or 2 for you

On my current project we are using FFmpeg because EE doesn't work with our pricing model and none of the .NET products for doing capture/transcoding are very good.